# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un correo electrónico llegó al destinatario, usando JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, javamail

He estado investigando un poco sobre el tema, y no he encontrado una solución al requerimiento que trabaje al 100%.

Una posible solución es pedir una confirmación de lectura utilizando el encabezado **"Disposition-Notification-To"** sin embargo no todos los clientes de correos tienen activada está función y al no ser una notificación automática depende de que el destinatario confirme el acuse de recibo.

Otra posible solución es utilizar una imagen incrustada en el contenido del correo, que llame un script, pero la mayoría de clientes de correo no cargan las imágenes.

Por lo que deseo saber si alguien ha encontrado una solución al requerimiento que funcione al 100% o pueda ayudarme al respecto.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentas, no hay forma 100% de confirmar que el correo electrónico llego al usuario.

En todas las posibles soluciones se depende del usuario, dos opciones que comentas son válidas, por ejemplo la confirmación por parte del usuario agregando la propiedad en el header:

```
email.AddHeaderField("Disposition-Notification-To", "\"BlahBlah Software\" <admin@blahblah.com>");
```

o un imagen que pueda realizar un "hit" que determine el usuario abrió el email.

Sin embargo una opción que implementamos para resolver esto de alguna manera, es que el usuario no reciba el mensaje completo y se tiene un enlace en el cual el usuario pude visualizar el mensaje completo, un script genera un "hit" que determina el mensaje fue leído.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios